# Stripping from a text file

Tags: python, string, text

If my text file contains this:

> ['A', 'B', 'C', 21, '25', 'D', '6', '8', '100', 'A']['Q', 'W', 'E', 21, '11', 'R', 'T', 3, 60, 'C']

and I want to collect the 1st item from each list into python- eg: A and Q. How would I do this?

I might want to collect the 3rd values later, eg C and E too

EDIT BELOW:
I now have the following code:

```
def ADMIN():
        print("Welcome")
        ADMINoption = input("Do you want option A or B.\n").upper()
        if ADMINoption == 'A':
            import re
            file = open('Membership.txt').read()
            temp = [re.split("\W+", i)[1:-1] for i in re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", file)]
            list_of_members = [i[0] for i in temp]
            print("The following are the usernames of the Members:")
            #print (*list_of_members)      THE * removes [] from list display
            for a in list_of_members:
                print (a)
            ADMINchoice=input("Select the member details you wish to inspect\n").upper()

ADMIN()
```

it produces the following:

```
"Welcome Do you want option A or B. a 
The following are the usernames of our members: 
DON21 
BAR50 
Select the member details you wish to inspect"
```

my text file contains:
['DON21', 'DONALD', 'TRUMP', 21, 'GYM', 'X', 'Easy', 5, 100, 'PO']['BAR50', 'BARACK', 'OBAMA', 50, 'SWIMMING', 'K', 'TRAINING', 3, 60, 'L']

How do I get the answer of the question to start returning the associated values from the list?
For example if I select 'DON21' it returns:
['DON21', 'DONALD', 'TRUMP', 21, 'GYM', 'X', 'Easy', 5, 100, 'PO']
or even a selection of the list such as 'TRUMP', 21, 'GYM'
??

Comment: have you tried anything or you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks 'wwii', I hadn't realised to be honest with you. I will look through the tutorial when I have more time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
d = [['A', 'B', 'C', 21, '25', 'D', '6', '8', '100', 'A'], ['Q', 'W', 'E', 21, '11', 'R', 'T', 3, 60, 'C']]
s = [i[0] for i in d]
```

Output:

```
['A', 'Q']
```

Accessing the data from the text file:

```
import re
data = open('filename.txt').read()
new_data = [re.split("\W+", i)[1:-1] for i in re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", data)]
final_data = [i[0] for i in new_data]
```

Comment: can d collect it from the text.txt?

Comment: its saying this error:  "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: @UKcodeNovice if this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: @UKcodeNovice just click on the checkmark box to the left of this question. Thanks!

Comment: @UKcodeNovice It will not close the thread as other users will still get to post answers.